# How do I type an anonymous PartialFunction

Tags: scala

This works:

```
scala> List(1, "aa") collect {  case n : Int => n+2 } 
res52: List[Int] = List(3)
```

And this works beautifully:

```
scala> var f:PartialFunction[Any, Int] = { case n : Int => n+2 }
f: PartialFunction[Any,Int] = <function1>

scala> var g:PartialFunction[Any, String] = { case n : String => n + " plus two " }
g: PartialFunction[Any,String] = <function1>

scala> List(1, "aa") collect (f orElse g)
res51: List[Any] = List(3, "aa plus two ")
```

But if I try to do the two together, nope:

```
scala> List(1, "aa") collect { case n : Int => n+2 } orElse { case n : String => n + " plus two " } 
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: PartialFunction[?,?]
              List(1, "aa") collect { case n : Int => n+2 } orElse { case n : String => n + " plus two " }
```

I don't understand exactly why the inference fails, but I can guess.  The important question: how do I fix it?

Comment: Just a blind guess, but try `List(1, "aa") collect (n:Any) => { case n : Int => n+2 } orElse (n:Any) => { case n : String => n + " plus two " }

Comment: @Malvolio Deleted my answer. I'm thinking you just can't declare a `PartialFunction` with a `case` statement unless the code expects there to be a `Function1` as the argument clause.

Comment: @wheaties -- for some reason, you can't declare it unless the context specified what kind of `PartialFunction` it is.  I was hoping there was some way I could easily specify it.  I don't think Dan's answer counts as "easy", though it is clever.

Comment: Yeah, I've been hoping that someone would show up with a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler the argument type of your anonymous `PartialFunction`s. You can do this directly, by annotating their types:

```
List(1, "aa") collect ({
  { case n : Int => n+2 }: PartialFunction[Any, _]
} orElse {
  { case n : String => n + " plus two " }: PartialFunction[Any, _]
})
```

Note that it's necessary to enclose the expression to the right of `collect` in parentheses.

If you don't like how wordy that is, and you don't mind frustrating whoever tries to understand your code, you could define an identity function on `PartialFunction`s with an input type of `Any`:

```
def pfa[T](f: PartialFunction[Any, T]): PartialFunction[Any, T] = f

List(1, "aa") collect (
  pfa { case n : Int => n+2 }
  orElse pfa { case n : String => n + " plus two " }
)
```

You could even come up with a suitably weird name and pretend it's a Scala language feature:

```
def @:[T](f: PartialFunction[Any, T]): PartialFunction[Any, T] = f

scala> @:{case x: Int => x + 3}
res29: PartialFunction[Any,Int] = <function1>
```